# Sent outbound email related to case Salesforce

Tags: email, case

We would like to place a custom email with template button inside a case layout. What should we do to ensure that if our client replies to that email, this gets automatically added to the case thread?

Answer (score 0):

Case emails usually contains the thread id, which helps Salesforce to recognize under which case it should attach the email. You can contain that thread id into those emails.

When creating template, you can use  **{!Case.Thread_Id}** in the template used on the button. Also make sure to make the appropriate settings in **email to case** settings.

Also go through the below link to know more:

[Check out the link.](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000IYu7QAG)

Comment: where should I place the thread id?

Comment: Insert Thread ID in the Email Subject **AND**

Insert Thread ID in the Email Body

Comment: any of them is fine

Comment: You should try with both places once, then try removing one at a time. I have implemented this in past, but don't exactly remember where did I place that. Please try at both.